# Mostrar etiqueta html if Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Quiero mostrar una etiqueta si hay datos para mostrar:

```
 <ng-template *ngIf="enableValidation(param.boolean)">
     <a href="{{param.link}}">
        <clr-icon shape="info-standard"></clr-icon> Acceder
       </a>
 </ng-template>
```

---

```
  enableValidation(exist: any) {
        if (exist === null) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

El problema es que no se muestra la etiqueta a> tenga o no tenga datos.
Gracias.

Edito, si es nulo que no haga nada, sino, declaro myData y pinto el a...
Pero tampoco me va..

```
 <div *ngIf="{{param.boolean}} === null ; else myData" >   </div>
     <ng-template #myData>
        <a href="{{param.link}}">
        <clr-icon shape="info-standard"></clr-icon> Acceder
          </a>
      </ng-template>
```

Comment: Buenas, si no es null que devuelve? creo que simplemente tendrías que hacer return exist == null y ya

Comment: sino es nulo... puede ser true o false....

Comment: @JackNavaRow Viene de una llamada de un servidor. Pero al existir el doublebindin ese, no debería dar problemas, creo

Comment: no deberias hacer algo como `*ngIf="param.boolean"`

Comment: porqué ? es un if

Comment: el params.boolean se compara con true o false, si viene el valor true se mostrara, en caso contrario no (null , undefined, false)

Comment: Tienes que llamarlo así: *ngIf="param.boolean == null" quita las llaves, no hacen falta y pon sólo 2 iguales para comparar el valor y no el tipo

Comment: ¿Podrías utilizar un `<ng-container>` en lugar del `<ng-tempalte>`?

Answer (score 2):

Según veo, quieres verificar si la propiedad `boolean` del objeto `param` existe o no para modificar el template. Basta con hacer:

```
<ng-template *ngIf="!!param.boolean">
    ...
</ng-template>
```

Te explico: la expresión `!variable` devuelve `true` si es que variable es `false` o `undefined` (no existe o no tiene ningún valor). Por ende, con !!variable estaríamos negando la expresión anterior, por lo que !!variable devolverá true si es que la variable existe, independiente de su valor.

En resumen, usamos `!!variable` para ver si es que la variable existe (o si tiene algún valor) y `!variable` para ver si es que no existe (o no tiene ningún valor) o si su valor es `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Valida si el objeto es **true** o distinto depende de tu operacion. pero ten cuidado si tienes un objeto en una variable

Te muestro un ejemplo para que veas a continuacion:

```js
let a ={
      var_1 : true,
      var_2 : false, 
      var_3 : null,
      var_4 : undefined, 
      var_5 : new Object()
 }


  
  for (x in a){
    if (a[x]) console.info(`el valor para ${x} en a es true  ${a[x]}`)
    if (!a[x]) console.warn(`el valor para ${x} NO TIENE EL VALOR TRUE ${a[x]}`)
  
  }
```

Comment: `if (a[x])` no solo devuelve `true` si el valor de la variable es `true`, si no que también devuelve `true` cuando la variable **tiene** un valor.

Comment: devuelve true cuando es true , o hay una funcion( intancia, objeto, array)